# Continuity of a function in a mixed discrete-connected domain

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Consider the following function $f: \mathbb{R} \times \left\{0,1\right\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}x, & (y=0) \\
k, & (y=1)
\end{cases}
$$

where $k$ is some real number. My question is: Is this function continuous on its domain (I know that if $x$ is fixed, it is continuous on $\left\{0,1\right\}$)? If it is, what would be the easiest way of proving it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it’s continuous. Let $U$ be any open set in $\Bbb R$. If $k\notin U$, then $f^{-1}[U]=U\times\{0\}$, which is open in $\Bbb R\times\{0,1\}$, and if $k\in U$, then $f^{-1}[U]=(U\times\{0\})\cup(\Bbb R\times\{1\})$, which is also open in $\Bbb R\times\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: @firemind: You’re very welcome.